# webdriver for testing frameworks when make a integration test java

Tags: frameworks, webdriver

I m a new one for selenium learning, I wonder that what kind of most you guys use when make a integration test. I mean, how do you manage your test cases in an excel? or anyother way?...And also how do you show your test result in a very straight way like a chart?
I searched some articles that they use ant+Junit+webdriver, any others?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Maven-TestNG-WebDriver is one of the effective way to create a framework. You can find details [**here**](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/start-your-webtests-with-selenium2-maven-testng-now). A framework setup cased on this is CI integration ready.

Another good options is FitNesse, which gives a wiki based test management / execution. Although it is not easy to integrate it to CI servers. FitNesse has web server based wiki which could help you in centralizing you automation test suites. Check it out **[here](http://veera-myseleniumblog.blogspot.in/2012/01/fitnesse-and-selenium.html)** and on **[FitNesse tutorials](http://fitnesse.org/FrontPage.FitNesseTutorials)**

BDD frameworks like JBehave can also be integrated with selenium. I will not recommend excel (which is good for tools like silktest and QTP) rat maintaining it on text files and / or wiki is much efficient and effective option. Again this is totally my opinion and you may find poi liberaries to be more helpful than I do.